# Pass an Object to a T4 Text Template

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I have a T4 Template that I am trying to pass object values to at runtime.

Basically what we're trying to to is:

1. From a Windows .NET form, read a file as text
2. Set an external object property to the text value
3. Access that object property in a T4 text template that has an output
   extension of .java.

I am starting very simple for now where I just have the template and the form and say an external class object:

[image: Flow]

Of course reading the text in the the form part and setting an object property like foo.foocode is fairly straightforward.

I just can't figure out how to access that object variable or property in the template and i've been looking at this for over a day..

Thanks

Comment: Doug, the question is not clear. You mention a custom t4 generator of yours and we don't have any clues on how it works. Also it is unclear what exact "runtime" you mention - a runtime of your custom generator, a runtime of t4 in the template class generation, a runtime of the class generated by t4 or a runtime of the code generated by the t4 generated class.

Comment: @Wiktor made some good points - have you tried adding `preprocessed template` (I think from code-generation folder) which generates both the .tt (w/ auto-gened .cs underneath it) + the *.partial.cs file? I think that's the shortest route to get you going. With that you have the 'object', class you can access, passing params into constructor + the .tt file which 'extends' that class and can use whatever you passed in. That all works more than fine and in much more complex scenarios.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity..

I'll update the post.

Comment: I tried the preprocessed template, but couldn't change the output type to .java.
thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity... are you making an UML or C# to Java tool?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At runtime you can only transform preprocessed templates, because the templating engine is not a redistributable part of Visual Studio. You can pass objects to a preprocessed templates using the [parameter directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586944.aspx). The object type you pass to the template must be decorated with the `SerializableAttribute`. Before calling the `TransformText()` method put the value of the parameter into the templating session.

The output extension directive is ignored when using a preprocessed template. The `TransformText()` method returns a string with the generated code. You can save it in whatever file type you want.

```
<#@ template debug="true" #>
<#@ parameter name="MyObject" type="MyNamespace.MyType" #>

<#
  // now access the passed parameter using
  this.MyObject
#>
```

Call the preprocessedTemplate:

```
var templateInstance = new MyTemplate();
templateInstance.Session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
templateInstance.Session.Add("MyObject", new MyType());
templateInstance.Initialize();

var generatedCode = templateInstance.TransformText();

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("outputfile.java", generatedCode);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't seem to have access to the public properties or methods of this public class using this method...

Not sure if I should or not.

Thanks

Comment: Apologies! I just tried it myself and noticed I forgot to initialize the template. The answer has been updated.

Comment: I guess what I meant to say is that intellisense doesn't seem to be working at design time.  In other words, I can't see the methods or properties at design time..

thanks again..

Comment: Visual Studio ships with no T4 template editor built in that provides intellisense as far as i know.

Comment: If you are using the tangible t4 editor (http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com) you can make intellisense available for you in your case: besides the <#@ parameter #> directive, reference the assembly containing MyType by a <#@ assembly #> directive and import the proper namespace with a <#@ import #> directive. That makes Intellisense for custom type parameters available...

Comment: error CS0400: Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'MyNamespace' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?).......Can anyone suggest something on this please?

Comment: The type 'MyNamespace.MyType' is an example for a type inside your Visual Studio Project of which you would like to pass an instance as a parameter into your T4 template at runtime. It should work if you create the proper class in that namespace. HTH

Comment: I don't have an Initialize() method in my generated class.  Just a TransformText() method.  How do I get it to generate an Initialize() method?  Or are they not needed anymore with VS2013?

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what I did, but as I started to build out my template, the Initialize() method just popped up when it wasn't there before.  Apparently something that you add to a template triggers the creation of the Initialize method.